# Crystal Reports 2008 HTML reports do not work with Internet Explorer 10 (IE10)

Tags: internet-explorer, crystal-reports

We have confirmed a bug in Crystal Reports 2008 (SP4) with Internet Explorer 10 clients.  It works with IE9 clients, but if you upgrade from IE9 to IE10 the failure occurs.

Specifically, you can view a report rendered as HTML, but when you close the report the request sent to the server hangs the thread on the server.  The code in IIS on the server is running

> CrystalDecisions.Web.dll!CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageCleaner.Run() + 0x4b bytes 
>        That method is, by design, an infinite loop.

I enabled `Failed Request Tracing` in IIS and the logs are here showing the error IIS server generates.

> error (2147943395) - The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)

This occurs if the IIS Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and also Windows 7 Server.
The problem does not occur for the IE9 browser, nor for Chrome or Firefox.

I suspect that something is causing Crystal to execute that `Run()` method and that should not be happening.

We tried using `EmulateIE7` and `EmulateIE9` in the document, and also in the browser client, and also both at the same time (not that it would make a difference), but browser emulation did not solve the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  We're not SAP or Microsoft, this site isn't for logging bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the question here that I posted on SAP but they didn't like the question and deleted it.  I guess I am looking for others that have hit this problem and to see if they found a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CR 2008 is up to service pack 5 now.
Second of all, CR 2008 only supports up to IE 9. See the release notes [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/e09fcfe0-d812-2f10-6eb6-a9ed5426cc5c?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&55959128973345).

Answer (score 0):

We upgraded some workstations to Internet Explorer 11 (IE11).  The problem did not occur once, but is consistently occurring again in IE11.